# Can you help me with preg_replace?

Tags: url, preg-replace

I have to replace some part of string, for another.

Original:

```
src="../../Estatico//ComunesSEI/Images/Supernet_logo.gif"
```

The result that I want :

```
src="https://empresas3.gruposantander.es/SEI_PARTENON_ENS/Estatico//ComunesSEI/Images/Supernet_logo.gif"
```

Problem : I have to change

```
src="../..
```

for

```
 src="src="https://empresas3.gruposantander.es/SEI_PARTENON_ENS
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you explain what you have tried?

Comment: i tried this


$pattern = '/src="\/..\/..\//';
    $replace = 'src="https://empresas3.gruposantander.es/SEI_PARTENON_ENS';
    
    $output = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$output);

Comment: Try escaping the `.` too. src="\/\.\.\/\.\.\//';

Comment: Also [try testing yourself](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=regex+tester+online)

Comment: i don't understand you :S can you explain or put an example ??

ths !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)?

```
$string = "../../Estatico//ComunesSEI/Images/Supernet_logo.gif";
$find = "../..";
$replace = "https://empresas3.gruposantander.es/SEI_PARTENON_ENS";

echo str_replace($find, $replcae $string);
```